# Swift 5: My barbutton in navigationbar wasn't fit

Tags: swift5

Here is my image:
[image]

And I put it in rightbarbuttonitem, and it is not fit with area.
This is result
[image]

Here is my code:

```
    let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
    button.setImage(UIImage (named: "Group 4"), for: .normal)
    button.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 35, height: 35)
    //button.addTarget(target, action: nil, for: .touchUpInside)
    let barButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButtonItem
```

Please help me!!!

Comment: Your links point to the same image.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this instead of your code?

```
let rightBarButtonItem = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 36, height: 36))
rightBarButtonItem.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "Group 4"), for: .normal)
rightBarButtonItem.addTarget(self, action: #selector(actionRightBar), for: .touchUpInside)
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: rightBarButtonItem)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).